# Why do C# StringBuilders not overload the += or + operators

Tags: c#, string, operator-overloading, stringbuilder

StringBuilders are meant to be used whenever large amounts of string concatenation occurs. In other words, when you have a lot of this

```
while(condition){
    s+="42";
}
```

or this

```
s = "1" + "a" + "unicorns"...;
```

Which gives us very clean and easily understandable code. So why aren't the same operators overloaded for StringBuilder? Is there a technical reason, or was it just a matter of style?

Comment: Those operators don't really make sense for a mutable object

Comment: Not sure why there are down-votes. It's a valid question.

Comment: @Tyler Can you expand on that...

Comment: This is not a question that is suited for SO.  It can be answered by the authors of the language/framework or nobody.  Thus it is opinion based and not constructive.

Comment: @KirkWoll Tyler seems to be hinting at some sort of concrete reason, not an opinion.

Comment: The `+` operator constructs a new object based on the two operands.  You shouldn't generally be constructing a new string builder based on two different operands, you should be mutating the string builder based on a single operand.

Comment: @Servy, it doesn't *have* to return a new string builder, though that would be a weird design to return one of the operands.

Comment: @Dgrin91 He's hinting at why it would be poor design, which is inherently an opinion, not a matter of fact.

Comment: @Servy Fair point for the `+`, but what about the `+=`. Its designed to mutate to object.

Comment: @Dgrin91, no it's not.   `foo += bar` is equivalent to `foo = foo + bar`.  That doesn't mutate the contents of `foo`, but rather assigns it to a new value.

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks. If someone would have just put this in an answer I would have accepted.

Comment: @Dgrin91 No, it's not.  First off, one can never overload the `+=` operator.  The `+=` operator is dependent on the implementation of the `+` operator, so overriding the `+` operator changes the behavior of the `+=` operator.  The `+=` operator *doesn't mutate a value, it mutates a variable*.  The `+=` operator evaluates the value of a variable, pass it along with the right hand side to the definition of the `+` operator, and then *mutates the variable to be the result of that operator*.